# Python script to automate tasks with Excel

Tags: python, excel

First of all I am very sorry if this is a common questions, however I am still very new in the programming world, and cannot figure out the keywords for what I'm actually looking for.

Basically I have an Excel spreadsheet with data [Picture of Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFAW7.png) - For each identifier I have a 0 or a 1. My task is to copy the number in the identifier column, paste it into a webpage from my workplace and click a button to exclude the customer from billing. Once I have done this, I will go back to the Excel spreadsheet and change the number from 0 to 1. Since there is a lot to go through, I thought this would be a fun project for me to start learning a basic script. I did not make it very far though!

```
import pandas as pd 

Migreringer = pd.read_excel('Migreringer.xls')

ExludeBilling = Migreringer[["Exclude Billing", "Identifier"]]

IsExcludedBilling = Migreringer["Exclude Billing"] > 0
```

I was hoping that someone was able to give me a good idea as to how to move on from here, My idea is that it would check each row for the True/False statement from IsExcludedBilling, and then as a start copy the identifier if the statement is False and paste it into a word document or something similar to test this out? I just cannot seem to figure out how to make Python go through each row and validate the statements, and then make it copy something from a different column in the same row to a different document?

I know from experience that I am more motivated in learning with a project in mind, so that is why I've chosen to start here. Maybe I should take a couple of steps back before engaging with a project like this?

Answer (score 1):

do you wan this ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Exclude Billing': [1,0,0,1,0],
        'Identifier': [ 41823,41835,41819,41798,41812],
    }
)
df_zero=df.loc[df['Exclude Billing']==0,:]
df_zero.to_csv('data_with_zero.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: That would definietly be a start, how would I go about adding the actual numbers from my sheet with this?

Comment: @SimonKianzad with df=pd.read_excel(your_files) and then you df_zero=df.loc…